# Swift - Unable to open local file in Safari

Tags: ios, swift, safari, openurl

I'm unable to open a local file in Safari using Swift's `openUrl()` function which keeps returning `false`:

```
let url = URL(string:"file:///Users/kiwitech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFA6761D-D98B-4C41-ACEF-18249F297897/data/Containers/Data/Application/82EF4E60-F9E9-434B-B86B-0391052D1E6E/Documents/proposals_dataxlsx.xlsx");

print("Local URL",url)
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url!) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url!, options: [:],completionHandler: {
            (success) in
            print("Open  \(success)")
        })
    } else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Im not sure if you can open a local file of another app on Safari. Why no open in in an UIWebView or WKWebView instead?

Answer (score 0):

To load File urls, you should use `Data(contentsOf: url)`, but if you want to open it you should use [UIDocumentInteractionController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller) instead.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

That's is correct only. find the canopenURL: definition.

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether or not the URL’s scheme can
>   be handled by some app installed on the device.

It means that whenever you query for **canOpenURL:(),** iOS will see if any of the installed apps are registered for the scheme that you are requesting, If it couldn't able to find anything, then it will **return false.**.

As the returning URL does not have any scheme attached to it, canOpenURL will return false. If you want to open a URL in Safari, it should start with **http:// or https://**, these are schemes registered for Safari.

One more thing is that, for canOpenURL(:), to work properly you need to whitelist the schemes. you can find more about this here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl

If you have registered custom schemes, then the respective app will open when you hit **open(url).**

one more thing, never hard code like the below.

```
let url = URL(string:"file:///Users/kiwitech/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FFA6761D-D98B-4C41-ACEF-18249F297897/data/Containers/Data/Application/82EF4E60-F9E9-434B-B86B-0391052D1E6E/Documents/proposals_dataxlsx.xlsx");
```

use NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains, to create or search for a file in the directories.

```
NSString *stringPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];
```

Comment: How do you whitelist file://?